# visual lag of the moving picture in Unity3D. How to make it smoother?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lag, frame-rate

I make a game in Unity3D (+2D ToolKit) for iOS.

It is 2d runner/platformer with side view. So on screen is moving background and obstacles. And we control up/down the main character to overcome obstacles.

The problem is that the moving picture has a visual lag. In other words, it moves jerkily or creates the tail area of the previous frames on iOS-devices. In XCode the number of frames is 30 and over.

I have objects 'plain' with the following script:

```
public class Move: Monobehavior
{
private float x;
public float Speed = 128.0f;
void Start()
{
x = transform.position.x;
}
void Update()
{
x += Time.DeltaTime *Speed;
Vector3 N = transform.position;
N.x = mathf.FloorInt(x);
transform.position = N;
}
}
```

The question is how to make the move of background smoother, without jerks and flicker on screen while playing? Maybe the problem is in framerate parameter.
Can anybody help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's the use of the FloorInt function which will move the background only in steps of 1 which is rather not smooth. It should get better when you comment that line out. Do you have any special reason why you are doing the FloorInt there?

Comment: public class Move: Monobehavior
    {
    private Vector3 P;
    public float Speed = 128.0f;
    void Start()
    {
    P = transform.position;
    }
    void FixedUpdate() {
    P.x += Time.fixeDeltaTime * Speed;
    transform.position = P;
    }
    }

Did it fixed and with decreased 'fixedDeltaTime' from default 0.02 to 0.01.
As a result - the same jerks, but just for smaller intervals...

Answer (score 0):

The use of floor will definitely hurt your performance. Not only is it one more thing to calculate, but it is actually removing fidelity by removing decimals. This will definalty make the movement look 'jerky'. Also, update is not always called on the same time inteval, depending on what else is happening during that frame, so using Time.delaTime is highly recommended. Another thing, you do not need to set variables for x and Vector3 N, when you can update the transoms position like the code below. And if you have to, you sill only need to create one variable to update, and set your position to it. The code below just updates the players x position at a given rate, based on the amount of time that has passes since the last update. There should be no 'jerky' movement. (Unless you have a serious framerate drop);

```
 public class Move: Monobehavior
    {
        public float Speed = 128.0f;

        void Update()
        {
            transform.position = 
                (transform.position.x + (speed*Time.DeltaTime), 
                transform.position.y,
                transform.position.z);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A little explaination to help the OP understand your solution wouldn't harm.

Comment: Right. Instead of trying to set all these float variables 'x' and 'n' and everything. Just simply update the players x position based on time, multiplied a certain rate 'speed'. This will be faster, and more efficient. The code above changes the transforms position in the x axis consistently with every call to update and keeps the y and z position exactly the same.